# Parallelize c program usin Openmp

Tags: c, openmp

I am a beginner openmp library user, I want to try to parallelize this portion of my c code, but that I don't actually see documentation on how to parallelize the user dynamic response portion. When I tried using:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);


    #pragma omp parallel

    {

     // gets user's input value
    int length = 100; //initial size
    char * keyVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    char * ivVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars

    char * cipherVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    int count = 0; //to keep track of how many chars have been used
    char c; // to store the current char

    printf("\n  Enter your key value : ");
    gets(keyVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your iv value : ");
    gets(ivVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your ciphertext : ");
    gets(cipherVal);

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
    if(count >= length)
        keyVal = realloc(keyVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        cipherVal = realloc(cipherVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        // plainValue = realloc(plainValue, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
    keyVal[count++] = c;
    ivVal[count++] = c;
    cipherVal[count++] = c;
 
    }

    time_t begin = time(NULL);

    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = keyVal;

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = ivVal;

    unsigned char *ciphertext=cipherVal;


    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext =(unsigned char *)"This is the top secret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";

    /*
     * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
     * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
     * algorithm and mode.
     */

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                              ciphertext);



    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);

    time_t end = time(NULL);
            printf("Time elpased is %ld seconds", (end - begin));
    }
}
```

It was showing output below:

[image]

However, I actually expect the prompt to occur only once per value. Please kindly help me as I have checked google severally to see what I am getting wrong but no result.

Comment: You should parallelize only the encrypt and decrypt part not the user intput

Comment: Thanks a lot @dreamcrash now solved.

Comment: The `while` loop containing the `realloc` is really scary. Note that `realloc` can run in `O(n)` time and copy all the previous data. Moreover, why do you do `length += 10` 3 times? `length` will likely be bigger than what you need and because the array have not the same size, I think it will likely cause a buffer overflow. Not to mention that parallelism here does not seems to be relevant, unless you want to parallelize the encrypt/decrypt calls as pointed out by @dreamcrash, but even in this case, the code need to be redesigned. Putting a `#pragma omp parallel` will not magically works.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks a lot for your review. I'll work on the pointed out issues.

Comment: I forgot to mention the `if(count >= length)` without any braces after. I do not see how this code can actually run correctly. First things first: you need to debug it first, then you can profile it to see if it needs optimizations, then you can optimize the sequential code and then it is worth optimizing it with OpenMP if this is not enough.

Comment: wow! I really appreciate @JérômeRichard your time and careful review.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I really appreciate. @dreamcrash

Comment: @dreamcrash assuming you have online course(or website) where you teach openmp I will gladly buy because I know that you will go into detail even to the least level and be readyt to answer even infant question.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Thanks :), no I don't have any.

Comment: There are helpful examples to be found [here](https://www.openmp.org//wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf) for OpenMP 4.5. One can also find similar documents for OpenMP 5.0 on the OpenMP website if needed, but the basics are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulG. it's really a good guide one.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi if you the encrypt and decrypt code you might get help with their parallelization

Comment: @dreamcrash yes, I actually want to encrypt and decrypt code using openssl library. That is why I want to learn parallelization. Still needs to work on the code according to your guide though.

Answer (score 0):

The working(gives the same output as the serial version) parallelized version is:
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

```
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    time_t begin = time(NULL);

    // gets user's input value
    int length = 100; //initial size
    char * keyVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    char * ivVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars

    char * cipherVal = malloc(length * sizeof(char)); //allocate mem for 100 chars
    int count = 0; //to keep track of how many chars have been used
    char c; // to store the current char

    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = keyVal;

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = ivVal;

    unsigned char *ciphertext=cipherVal;

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    printf("\n  Enter your key value : ");
    gets(keyVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your iv value : ");
    gets(ivVal);

    printf("\n  Enter your ciphertext : ");
    gets(cipherVal);


    #pragma omp parallel

    {

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){ //keep reading until a newline
    if(count >= length)
        keyVal = realloc(keyVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        ivVal = realloc(ivVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        cipherVal = realloc(cipherVal, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
        // plainValue = realloc(plainValue, (length += 10) * sizeof(char)); //add room for 10 more chars
    keyVal[count++] = c;
    ivVal[count++] = c;
    cipherVal[count++] = c;
 
    }


        #pragma omp critical
        {
            /* Message to be encrypted */
            unsigned char *plaintext =(unsigned char *)"This is the top secret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";

            /*
            * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
            * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
            * algorithm and mode.
            */

            /* Encrypt the plaintext */
            ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                                    ciphertext);
        }
    }

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);

    time_t end = time(NULL);
            printf("Time elpased is %ld seconds", (end - begin));
}
```